# Team Foundation Server 2005 API

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to retrieve a list of build definitions for a given team project name using the TFS 2005 Api.

For TFS 2010 and onwards, the normal procedure to do this would be:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(Uri));

        IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        var buildDefinitions = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(projectName);
```

This would normally return an array of IBuildDefinition and I can query the name property.

However, in this case I am trying to access a TFS 2005 server and it gives the exception:

> "NotSupportedException - TF214015: The build client object model does not support Team Foundation >Server 2005".

Could anybody suggest the best way to retrieve a list of build definitions? **Upgrading the 2005 server is not an option at this moment.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2005 you could only access the actual builds themselves (i.e. the results of a build), not the build definitions. Querying build definitions was only added with TFS 2008.

*Note: I'm working from memory here, so I may be wrong, but the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.builddefinition.aspx) backs me up (see the 'other versions' drop down)